# Sequelize hasOne join: Include unexpected. Element has to be either a Model, an Association or an object

Tags: node.js, angular, orm, sequelize.js

I want to establish a relationship between two tables using a foreign key to read me the description (funzione string(40)). My models and code:

---

### first model:

```
id: {
      autoIncrement: true,
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    id_user: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false
    },
    id_role: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false
    },
    id_funzione: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false
    }
  }, {
    sequelize,
    tableName: 'abilitazioni',
    schema: 'public',
    timestamps: false,
    indexes: [
      {
        name: "pk_abilitazioni",
        unique: true,
        fields: [
          { name: "id"},
        ]
      },
    ]
```

### Second model:

```
id: {
      autoIncrement: true,
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true
    
    },
    funzione: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING(40),
      allowNull: false
    }
  }, {
    sequelize,
    tableName: 'funzioni',
    schema: 'public',
    timestamps: false,
    indexes: [
      {
        name: "pk_funzioni",
        unique: true,
        fields: [
          { name: "id_funzione" },
        ]
      },
    ]
```

### The relation

```
db.Abilitazioni.hasOne(db.Funzioni, {
   foreignKey: 'id_funzione'
   });
   db.Funzioni.belongsTo(db.Abilitazioni);
```

### find on db

```
Abilitazioni.findAll({
            where: { id_role: id
            },
            include: [{
                Funzioni, 
            }]
        })
```

> I tried to create a one to one relationship to read a description
> field with the foreign key.
>
> ```
> This query : 
> SELECT funzioni.id , funzioni.funzione , funzioni.access_level
> from public.abilitazioni, public.funzioni
>  where abilitazioni.id_user = 1 and id_role= 1 and
> ```
>
> abilitazioni.id_funzione = funzioni.id ;